# Laravel run composer / git commands within controller

Tags: php, shell, cmd, laravel-5, composer-php

is it possible to run composer or git commands from within a controller in Laravel? Something like that:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function shell(Request $request){
        if($request->isMethod('post')){


            $data['output'] = shell_exec('composer update');
            // or some git commands
            return view('tests.shell', $data);
        } else {
            return view('tests.shell');
        }
    }
}
```

If I do it the way shown above, I get no message. I think, the problem is, that these commands have to be run in the projects root directory and not in an subfolder.

And is there a php function to run a complete shell script and not only single commands?

I have tested this:

```
echo shell_exec('php ' . __DIR__ . '/../shell.php');
// shell.php is in projects root directory
```

The script is executed, but not in the root directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't noticed it before, but Laravel ships with a tool to run terminal commands/composer commands. You can use the [The Process Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) from Symfony. So it becomes very easy to run commands.

An example for Laravel 5.2:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

class SetupController extends Controller
{
    public function setup(){
        $migration = new Process("php artisan migrate");

        $migration->setWorkingDirectory(base_path());

        $migration->run();

        if($migration->isSuccessful()){
            //...
        } else {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($migration);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$data['output'] = shell_exec( '(cd '. base_path() .' && /usr/local/bin/composer info)' );

// debug
dd( $data );
```

The command is in `(` and `)` so that we mode to the root folder if the project and the execute `composer info`.

The following git command also works too, but not `git pull` or `git fetch`:

```
$data['output'] = shell_exec( '(cd '. base_path() .' && /usr/bin/git status)' )
```

I've also tried the `/usr/local/bin/composer update` command, but as you have to wait for the packages to update the script either returns `null` or times out.

Its also worth pointing out that the full path to composer / git should be used, i.e. `/usr/local/bin/composer` or you will always see `null` returned.

For your PHP script, try something similar to:

```
echo shell_exec('(cd '. base_path() .' && php shell.php)');
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want to log the output of the command to file and attempt to capture in PHP, you can try:

```
$data['output'] = shell_exec( '(cd '. base_path() .' && /usr/bin/git status | tee -a file.log)' )
```

The `tee -a file.log` part will save output to `file.log` as well as output to screen (so `shell_exec` can pickup output), and the `-a` flag will append new output to the file if it already exists (useful if you want to have one log file with historical record of previous commands).

Comment: Everything works fine in my local environment. But I have no success in my laravel installation. The result is NULL. I also have tried to execute other commands than composer / git (e.g. php artisan make:controller XyzController) but with no success...

Comment: I've had mixed results too. Some commands work perfectly, while others return ```null```. Could be related to the type of output generated by the command or PHP timing out...

Comment: Do you know a way to log the actions? It's difficult to check if an command succeeded or not when there is no output^^

Comment: I've started a diskussion on  [laracasts.com](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/running-cmd-commands-shell-scripts-from-controller). I will try this later and will give you a feedback if you want.

Comment: If you want to log the output you can do ```$data['output'] = shell_exec( '(cd '. base_path() .' && /usr/bin/git status | tee -a file.log)' )```. The ```tee -a file.log``` will save output to ```file.log``` as well as output to screen, and the ```-a``` flag will append new output to the file.